# При попытке установки Wordpress открывается содержимое wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress, vps

Пытаюсь установить Wordpress.

1. Скачал последнюю версию `wget https://wordpress.org/latest.zip`
2. Распаковал в свою директорию на сервере `/var/www/wplearn/html`
3. Перенес содержимое из `/var/www/wplearn/html/wordpress` в `/var/www/wplearn/html`
4. Настроил конфиг `nginx` **(вместо wp.example.site в реальном конфиге мой адрес)**

```nginx
    server {

        server_name wp.example.site;

        root /var/www/wplearn/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        access_log /var/www/wplearn/log/access.log; 
        error_log /var/www/wplearn/log/error.log;

        keepalive_timeout       60; 

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
            rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
        }

        location ~* /wp-sitemap.*\.xml {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # error_page 404 /404.html;
        # error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        client_max_body_size 20M;

        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/www/wplearn/html;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { 
            log_not_found off; 
            access_log off; 
        }

        location = /robots.txt { 
            rewrite ^ /robots.txt break; 
            allow all; 
            log_not_found off; 
            access_log off; 
        }

        location ~ /\.ht { 
            deny all; 
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/wplearn/html/;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/wplearn/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED /var/www/wplearn/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

            # Add headers to serve security related headers
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }

        #enable gzip compression
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        gzip_types application/json text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;
        gzip_proxied any;

        # A long browser cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page
        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
            access_log        off;
            log_not_found     off;
            expires           360d;
        }

        # disable access to hidden files
        location ~ /\.ht {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            deny all;
        }

    }
```

5. Создал базу данных для вордпресса.
6. Скопировал конфиг вордпресса `cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php` и вставил там данные своей БД

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wplearn' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'wplearn' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'тут мой пароль' );
```

7. Поменял `$table_prefix = 'wp_';` на свой префикс

Ну и конечно же перезагружал `nginx`.

После этого запустил свой сайт wp.example.site (также пробовал wp.example.site/wp-admin/install.php)

Мне выдает содержимое моего `wp-config.php` будто это обычный текстовый файл.

Я уж было подумал, может с PHP что-то не так и попробовал создать файл test.php со следующим содержимым:

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Открыл его `wp.example.site/test.php` - все работает как полагается.

## Что я делаю не так?

*Wordpress очень давно ставил и это было на виртуальном хостинге. А тут решил на VPS попробовать и вот такая беда.*

Comment: Удали конфиг ВП и зайти по своему домену.

Comment: Неправильная настройка кофига nginxю Инструкция: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/nginx/

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо! Это сработало.